# Who/what is the dying infant-like creature in the limbo King's Cross, around the end of Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

When Harry has been hit with the killing curse, he ends up in an imaginary King's Cross, with Dumbledore, and an infant-like creature that can be heard crying.

**What is this creature?**

[image: An emaciated, naked, small human-like creature covered in sores, curled up on the floor.]

Comment: how exactly does that look like a "baby" to you?

Comment: @AwalGarg I believe in the books it is explicitly called "a baby".

Comment: @Bakuriu, That's what I recall from the book as well, though I admit that it's been a while.

Comment: I'll defend the OP; it looks a bit like [Benjamin Button](http://theinkbrain.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/brad-pitt-old-benjamin-button-32.jpg).

Comment: @AwalGarg so disappointed you're more influenced by the films than the books...

Answer (score 62):

**Part of Voldemort’s soul.**

This was an FAQ on [J.K. Rowling’s old website](http://web.archive.org/web/20080215132258/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=121):

> **What exactly was the mutilated baby-like creature Harry saw at King’s Cross in chapter 35 of “Hallows”?**
>
> I’ve been asked this a LOT. It is the last piece of soul Voldemort possesses. When Voldemort attacks Harry, they both fall temporarily unconscious, and both their souls – Harry’s undamaged and healthy, Voldemort’s stunted and maimed – appear in the limbo where Harry meets Dumbledore.

This is hinted at in the text of the book, and this interpretation fits with what Dumbledore says, but I don’t think it’s made explicit.

Comment: http://37.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ln3231bSBE1qa0uujo1_1280.png

Comment: Didn't Nagini come before Harry?

Comment: @Richard - I never thought of that, but that would explain why the diary was so *animate* compared to the other horcruxes.

Comment: @Richard Interesting link, but as Voldemort always intended to split himself into seven, perhaps he was skilled enough to put a seventh into each horcrux? (allowing for the mistake of making Harry one)

Comment: @Bobson That's a good point too.

Comment: @Richard - And surprisingly (and unintentionally) all Horcruxes were destroyed in the same order.

Comment: So are we to understand that there is one such creature in the limbo (somewhere) for each of the 8 pieces of Voldemort's soul? Rather than one single creature representing Voldemort? I think that is what the OP intends to clarify.

Comment: @Mynamite But if he was skilled to put away 1/7th of his soul, he'd know he was missing some soul for the post-Harry Horcruxes

Comment: @Richard If the split was 50% of the remainder each time, as your link suggests, it would also explain how each horcrux is successively less powerful when it is destroyed.The diary takes an active part in events and can think and speak; the ring casts a powerful curse on Dumbledore which cannot be cured; the locket merely tries to get inside Ron's mind; in the book we don't hear what happens when R&H destroy the cup, but the emerge unscathed; the diadem is destroyed by fire without fighting back; Nagini is killed like any ordinary snake.

Comment: @Mynamite `Nagini is killed like any ordinary snake` Ordinary snakes aren't killed with Gryffindor's sword you know. :P

Comment: @BabyMan True, but Nagini dies without any fight-back - there is no kind of curse rebounding on Neville.

Comment: @Myanmite the curse on the ring wasn't part of the horcrux but something Riddle added to protect it, perhaps in order to compensate for leaving it in a comparatively discoverable location. It might be impossible/unwise to apply the same curse on a living being. None of the other horcruxes are protected in this way. As for the diadem, Fiendyfire is a rare form of dark magic that utterly destroys whatever it touches.

Comment: This assumption that it was split in half every time always seemed a bit strange to me. The way I'd read the books, it never said how much of your soul you needed to put in the object (part of your soul, not half of your soul). I'd always thought he either intended to divide it equally into 7 or alternatively just tear off chunks of soul to put into the horcruxes. The latter always seemed more likely as the talk tended to be of him mutilating his soul as opposed to slicing it up.

Answer (score 18):

It makes me think back to *Goblet of Fire*, where Wormtail is carrying a baby-like form of Voldemort, i.e. the materialisation of a part of Voldemort's soul (i.e. Horcrux).

Maybe this is another part of Voldemort's soul, the one that is/was trapped in Harry's body until now. The killing curse has separated them, Harry can leave it to die in order to make Voldemort mortal (and consequently loses his Parselmouth).

Answer (score 1):

It was part of Voldemort's  soul that resides in Harry's body.

Since Voldemort and Harry have a connection (due to the something that hit Harry the night his parents died), Harry has a piece of Voldemort's soul inside him and that is why he can speak Parseltongue, look into Voldemort's mind, etc.

Answer (score -1):

the killing curse seperated voldy's sub-soul from harry, and it was maimed and in pain. dumbledore says "something beyond either of our help", it could not go "on" like dumbledore, or back to voldemort's body, it's something like a piece of garbage that even voldemort didnt know existed

Answer (score -1):

When Harry asked Dumbledore "what exactly is that?" D responded "something beyond our help, a part of voldemort sent here to die"  This is the quote from the movie.  I think the book might explain better.  It did look like the "baby" Voldemort wormtail was holding...the one that the muggle saw when he walked into the house where wormtail and the other guy were at

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  As it stands this answer is likely to get downvoted because it doesn't really address the question.  You may wish to consider revising this answer so that it provides more information

Answer (score -1):

Voldemort's soul was divided in many parts. The parts of his soul that got destroyed could not move on, as the soul had not completely died. 
So I think this unusual baby like creature was how Voldemort's half destroyed soul was depicted. 
What I mean to say is probably this is the 6/8 part of his soul leading a very pathetic/painful existence on the other side because it cannot move on. So it's stuck in the limbo as well.