# Voldemort's soul split and attached itself to Harry; so why did he die while his spirit was alive in Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

If part of Voldemort's spirit is alive, can't he be resurrected again?
Like several times before?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the specific quote regarding Voldemort destroying that piece of his soul. I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  When Voldy killed Harry in the forest, he killed the part of his soul that was attached to Harry's soul. This was the weird creature that Harry saw in King's Cross.

> He recoiled. He had spotted the thing that was making the noises. It had the form of a small, naked child, curled on the ground, its skin raw and rough, flayed-looking, and it lay shuddering under a seat where it had been left, unwanted, stuffed out of sight, struggling for breath.
>
> He was afraid of it. Small and fragile and wounded though it was, he did not want to approach it. Nevertheless he drew slowly nearer, ready to jump back at any moment. Soon he stood near enough to touch it, yet he could not bring himself to do it. He felt like a coward. He ought to comfort it, but it repulsed him.
>
> “You cannot help.”

That was the piece of Voldemort's soul that was killed.

Also the reason for this:

> “So the boy . . . the boy must die?” asked Snape quite calmly.
>
> “And Voldemort himself must do it, Severus. That is essential.”

Comment: @NKCampbell I don't know what you are talking about...

Comment: Why do you think the “creature” was the soul fragments that had been in Harry, and not the remaining main part of Voldemort’s soul?

Comment: @chirlu The soul fragments were dead.  Voldemort was not

Comment: Harry was in the limbo and not dead.

Comment: Dumbledore was in the limbo and dead.  Therefore, it makes sense that the soul fragments also could be there.  Voldemort, though, was alive, and could not be there.

Comment: Voldemort passed out in the same way as Harry and awoke at the same time, i.e. when Harry had decided to return from the limbo.

Comment: @chirlu But he wasn't in the limbo.  There was no way for him to be killed or get to limbo while Nagini lived.

Comment: Looks like chirlu is right about this.  See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/65375/5930 for a Word of God quote.

Answer (score 9):

The portion of his spirit that was inside Harry was gone.

When Voldemort tried killing Harry in the Forbidden Forest, Harry's spirit went to the King's Cross Station area where he spoke with Dumbledore's spirit. There, we also see the monstrous, mewling baby-like creature that was Voldemort's soul.

This prompts Harry to ask about what happened to the part of Voldemort that had been inside him.

> “So the part of his soul that was in me…”
>   Dumbledore nodded still more enthusiastically, urging Harry onward, a broad smile of encouragement on his face.
>   “… has it gone?”
>   “Oh yes!” said Dumbledore. “**Yes, he destroyed it.** Your soul is whole, and completely your own, Harry.”

So when Voldemort was killed, all of his remaining soul, that decrepit child-like creature we saw in limbo,  was in his Voldemort's own body, and Harry's soul was "completely" his own.

Also see: [Who/what is the dying infant-like creature in the limbo King's Cross, around the end of Deathly Hallows?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/65373/31178) for more information about Voldermort's soul.